# Java GUI showInputDialog

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, joptionpane

how can i extract the selected value?? i mean if *"Vital"* is selected by user , i need to get value 0, or value 1 for *"Olympic"*

```
Object[] possibleValues = { "Vital", "Olympic", "Third" };
Object selectedValue = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
"Choose one", "Input",
JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, null,
possibleValues, possibleValues[0]);
```

i had a previous code which worked fine with a showConfirmDialog box.

```
int choice = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Click Yes for Rectangles, No for Ovals");
    if (choice==2)
    {
        return ;
    }
    
    if (choice==0) 
    {
        choice=5;
        
    }
    if (choice==1)
    {
        choice=6;
    }

    Shapes1 panel = new Shapes1(choice);
```

this worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is giving you the text representation, add a method to convert the text value to a numerical index if that's what you need. An O(1) way of doing this would be to create a map ahead of time if these values are constant:

```
Map<String, Integer> valueToIndex = new HashMap<>();
valueToIndex.put("Vital", 0);
valueToIndex.put("Olympic", 1);
valueToIndex.put("Third", 2);
```

Then it's just

```
int index = valueToIndex.get((String) selectedValue)
```

If instead it's something you'll only be doing once, don't bother creating the map. Just iterate over the possible values until you find the index of `selectedValue`

```
int indexFor(Object selectedValue, Object possibleValues) {
    for (int i = 0; i < possibleValues.length; i++) {
        if (possibleValues[i].equals(selectedValue)) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    throw new RuntimeException("No index found for " + selectedValue);
}
```

And then call this method:

```
int index = indexFor(selectedValue, possibleValues);
```

Comment: first line of first solution will be HashMap<String, Integer> valueToIndex = new HashMap<>(); , other than that, your solution worked beautifully, thank you .